# "Dynamic" type when filtering object keys

Tags: typescript, api

Let's say that I have the following payload:

`{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}`

And I want to have a function that, given an object, picks some keys and returns a type accordingly.

```
function pick<T>(obj: any, ...keys: string[]): T {
  return (
    Object.fromEntries(
      keys
        .filter(key => key in obj)
        .map(key => [key, obj[key]])
    )
  ) as T;
}

const test = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

type Foo = {
  a: number,
  b: number
}
const result = pick<Foo>(test, 'a', 'b');
console.log(result);
```

Is there a way to handle this better? I understand that using type coercion is pretty much shutting down Typescript safety-net.

For example, if I do this:

```
console.log(pick<Foo>(test, 'b'));
```

I am telling typescript that the function pick returns a Foo object, yet it doesn't have the key `a` defined.

The use case is that we have API calls that we:

1. Have to type
2. Only want to type the relevant keys for our use case
3. Do it following TS best practices

Answer (score 2):

If you're okay with the implementation of `pick` not typechecking, then you can at least make the types all line up. The super-handy Typescript type we're going to use for this is actually called [`Pick`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys).

```
function pick<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, ...keys: K[]): Pick<T, K> {
  return (
    Object.fromEntries(
      keys
        .filter(key => key in obj)
        .map(key => [key, obj[key]])
    )
  ) as any;
}
```

The function implementation is the exact same, except that at the end we cast through `any`, which effectively tells Typescript to trust us. `Pick<T, K>` is exactly the type you want: it says "take the type `T`, subscript it with the type `K`, and see what we get". `K` is an arbitrary type that extends `keyof T`. Assuming you pass constant arguments to this function, you'll get a union of literals type like `"a" | "b"` for `K`.

I don't know of a way to get `Object.fromEntries` to typecheck, short of casting through `any` like we did above. In my experience, when you start messing with functions on the `Object` prototype, you have to coax Typescript along a little bit to get the right types on things.

Comment: return this error in `obj`.
'Argument of type 'T' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [s: string]: unknown; } | ArrayLike<unknown>'.
      Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'ArrayLike<unknown>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(o: {}): [string, any][]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'T' is not assignable to parameter of type '{}'.'

Comment: This answer worked for me when I changed the definition to: `pick<V, T extends Record<K, V>, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, ...keys: K[]): Pick<T, K>`. That solved the error the commenter above had.

Answer (score 0):

Silvio's answer works with the adjustment I posted in the comments, but it looks like Lodash supports this with `_.pick` if you want to depend on that.

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#pick

It works exactly how you (and I!) wanted.